# string value as resource key in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, markup-extensions

In my WPF solution I have created a custom translate markup extension. I am using the inputed key as the default language string to display. When user changes language I just update the resource binding value to the translated version.
This is really sweet if end-user does not want to have multiple languages and he does not want to maintain separate resource file.

The problem is that I can't surround the key with `""`.
This means that if a comma exists in the string then it was interpreted as multiple keys. I solved that by wrapping special `""` around the key:

```xml
&quot;  <!-- Double quote symbol -->
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-use-special-characters-in-xaml

The syntax is really messy if I want to have comma in the text/key. Also color highlighting goes wild.

```
<Label Content="{l:Translate Some kind of string}"/>
<Label Content="{l:Translate &quot;With comma, not causing trouble if quoted&quot;}"/>
```

Is there any other way to write the key inline where the XAML editor does not go crazy and I don't need to add special `"` in front of key and after key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very easy solution to your problem: Wrap your string in single quotes (`'`). Everything you need to know about how Markup Extensions are processed can be found [in this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200269.aspx).

The gist of it:

> The text value of either a MEMBERNAME or STRING is read as follows. Leading whitespace characters are consumed without being represented in the generated token. **If the first non-whitespace character is a quote** (either Unicode code point 0022, Quotation Mark, or 0027, Apostrophe), the tokenizer proceeds as follows:
>
> The first quote is consumed and is not represented in the token’s value.
>
> The text value becomes the characters up to but not including the next matching quote (i.e. a character of the same code point as the opening quote) that is not preceded by a “\” character. All these characters and also the closing quote are consumed. Any “\” characters in the resulting text value are removed.
>
> Whitespace characters following the closing quote are consumed, and are not represented in the token.

So you can just write it like this:

```
<Label Content="{l:Translate 'With comma, not causing trouble if quoted'}"/>
```

---

If you want to get rid of any kind of quotes altogether, you could of course resort to a hacky workaround like this:

```
public TranslateExtension(string value1, string value2)
{
    _value = value1 + ", " + value2;
}

public TranslateExtension(string value1, string value2, string value3)
{
    _value = value1 + ", " + value2 + ", " + value3;
}

// etc.
```

That would of course potentially mess up your whitespaces and unfortunately MarkupExtensions can't utilize the `params` keyword, so you would have to add constructors for any number of commas.

Comment: Yes I did the hacky solution when I created the markup extension but quickly discarded it. Seems like the single quote solution is completely what I need.